# Config JMSSerializer during runtime

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I have 2 associated entities, `Venue` and `Promo` (many to many).

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
class Venue {
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Promo", inversedBy="venues")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="promo_venues")
     * @JMS\Exclude()
     */
    private $promos;

    ...
}
```

And

```
class Promo{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Venue", mappedBy="promos")
     * @JMS\Exclude()
     */
    private $venues;
}
```

I'm writing a RESTful API that outputs the data of these tables. In an action, I need the output the `venues` associated with a promotion (1). In another, I need to output the list of `venues` without promotion data (2).

To solve (1), I can simply remote the Exclude annotation in `Promo::venues`. However, this will cause the `venues` list to be output in (2), which is undesirable.

I looked into the code and found that JMS's `Serializer` doesn't provide getters for its members.

Question: Is there any way to update the serialiser config on the fly (inside a controller), particularly adding/removing a field-level configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Groups Exclusion Strategy](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies).

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

class Venue {
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Promo", inversedBy="venues")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="promo_venues")
     */
     private $promos;

     ...
}

class Promo{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Promo", mappedBy="promos")
     * @JMS\Groups("onlyVenues")
     */
    private $venues;
}
```

In your controller, you can do for (2):

```
$serializer->serialize($entities, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('onlyVenues')));
```

For (1), serialize without setting any groups (i.e. no exclusion strategies are applied).

Comment: Not the exact solution but thanks for pointing out the Group strategy. Just noticed that this can be set via annotation inside the controller. Somehow I overlooked the FOSRestBundle documentation :)

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md

Comment: Actually, it's the solution for this particular question ^_^